# Error while copying data from one sheet to another using vba

Tags: excel, vba

While copying data from `Sheet1` to `Sheet2` I am getting

> "Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error"

I am using vba code:

```
lnRow = 33
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A3:C14").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range(Cells(lnRow + 3, 1))
```

How can I copy data from `Sheet1` to `Sheet2` using `column` numbers?

Comment: A range needs the first cell and the last cell, you are feeding only the first cell, use `Cells` instead like this: `Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(lnRow + 3, 1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the problematic part is `Sheets("Sheet2").Range(Cells(lnRow + 3, 1))` and there are 2 issues with it.

#### 1. Issue

For the `Cells` object there is not specified in which worksheet it is so VBA assumes `ActiveSheet`. It is the same as writing `Sheets("Sheet2").Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(lnRow + 3, 1))`.

Now if the active sheet is **not** `Sheet2` then the code will fail because the `Range` object is not in the same sheet as the `Cells` object, and that is not allowed.

#### 2. Issue

According to the documentation of the [Worksheet.Range property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.range) it accepts 2 arguments `Range(Cell1, Cell2)` where the second is optional, but **only if the first is an address string**.

> `Cell1`
>
> - *A **String** that is a range reference when **one** argument is used.*
> - *Either a **String** that is a range reference or a **Range** object when **two** arguments are used.*

So that means you can use the following syntax:

- `Range("Address")`
- `Range("Address", "Address")`
- `Range(Cells(row, column), Cells(row, column))`

but you cannot use

- `Range(Cells(row, column))`

because if only one argument is used it must be a string/address. Actually the last one does not exist because you then can use `Cells` directly without using `Range`: `Cells(row, column)`

---

So in your case that means you must use `Cells` directly:

```
Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(lnRow + 3, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the cells method then the error is due to the usage of `range(cells(3,1))`. Instead use `sheets("Sheet1").range(cells(3,1),cells(4,1))`. Otherwise you can omit the cells and specify the range as usual e.g. `range("C4:D5")`.

Comment: There is no problem if the range is 10000x bigger on the source, when you copy 300 cells and paste just in one cell, excel will paste it anyway. Try it.

Comment: Actually this will fail. This code only works if the active sheet is `Sheet1` because the cells `Cells(3, 1), Cells(4, 1)` refer to active sheet but the `Range` referst to `Sheets("Sheet1")`. **Every** objects referring to a cell or range should specify in which workbook/worksheet they are or you will easily run into unreliable code. • Actually you run into *issue 1* of my answer and @Damian is right too, that's actually no problem.